# I got type mismatch erroron my VBA code and can+t fix it. ow can i solve this?

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch, mismatch

```
'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim MySheetu As String, ws As Worksheet
MySheetu = operationplan.Value
Set ws = Worksheets(MySheetu)

Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Variant
Dim d As Variant
Dim e As Variant
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim lastrow3 As Long
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant
Dim k As Variant


Dim dsheet As Worksheet
lastrow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To lastrow
ws.Cells((a), 1).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(a, 21).Value
ws.Cells((a), 2).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(a, 22).Value
ws.Cells((a), 3).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(a, 23).Value
ws.Cells((a), 4).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(a, 20).Value
ws.Cells((a), 5).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(a, 26).Value
ws.Cells((a), 6).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(a, 1).Value
ws.Cells((a), 7).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(a, 1).Value
Next a
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "operasyon"
ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "öncelik"
ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "ardillik"
ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "operasyon süresi"
ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "sabit istasyon"
ws.Cells(1, 6).Value = "distinct_istasyon"
ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = "istasyon"

Columns(6).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)


For b = lastrow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(b, 1).Text = "#N/A" Then
Rows(b).Delete
End If
Next b
lastrow2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



For i = 2 To lastrow2
    For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws.Cells(j, 2).Value Then
            ws.Cells((j), 2) = i - 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i'
```

I got type mismatch error in the last fifth row that is "If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws.Cells(j, 2).Value Then" How can I solve this.It is try to refer worksheet by using user form txt box value. In debugging it can be seen that I can get text box value but worksheet give type mismatch error.

Comment: You’ve asked this question twice. Did you look into the comments on your first attempt?

Comment: yes i look and int he previous one someone want to see whole code but I cant add whole code as comment so I post it as another question

Comment: You should be able to just edit the question.

Comment: Are column A and B on ws both numeric ? What are the last 7 lines of code trying to do ?